# make the date validation for filing leave and it must be <15 days. the problem is that the appropriate code bug leave is also rejected

Tags: php, datetime

```
if(isset($_POST['btncuti'])){
  if($_POST['jenis_cuti'] == "Cuti Tahunan"){
    $date1=date_create($_POST['mulai_tanggal']);
    $date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
    $diff=date_diff($data1,$data2);
  }
  if($diff < 15){
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO: Date must be 15 days");</script>';
  }
}
else {
```

make the date validation for filing leave and it must be <15 days. the problem is that the appropriate code bug leave is also rejected

Answer (score 0):

`$diff` is an object, and does not hold that value directly - you have to access the `days` property instead, which holds the number of days that is the difference between the two dates.

```
if ($diff->days < 15) {
```

- http://php.net/class.dateinterval

Comment: still a bug, <15 days a warning still appears INFO: Date must be 15 days

Comment: if(isset($_POST['btncuti'])){

    if($_POST['jenis_cuti'] == "Cuti Tahunan"){
        $date1=date_create($_POST['mulai_tanggal']);
        $date2=date_create($_POST['sampai_tanggal']);
        $date3=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
        $diff=date_diff($data1,$data2,$data3);
        
    if ($diff->days < 15) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO: Date must be 15 days");</script>';
    }
    }
}
else {

Comment: What is the value of `var_dump($diff->days);`?

Answer (score 0):

```
my code : if(isset($_POST['btncuti'])){
// Validasi Cuti Tahunan
    if($_POST['jenis_cuti'] == "Cuti Tahunan"){

        $date1=date_create($_POST['mulai_tanggal']);
        $date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
        $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

        if($diff->d >= 30){
        // if($diff->d == 30){
            $jeniscuti =  $_POST['jenis_cuti'];
            $alasancuti = $_POST['alasan_cuti'];
            $jumlahcuti = $_POST['jumlah_cuti'];
            $mulaitanggal = $_POST['mulai_tanggal'];
            $sampaitanggal = $_POST['sampai_tanggal'];
            $alamat1 = $_POST['alamat'];
            $nohp1 = $_POST['nohp'];

            $query="INSERT INTO cuti VALUES('null', '$jeniscuti','$alasancuti','$jumlahcuti','$mulaitanggal','$sampaitanggal','$alamat1','$nohp1', 'dalam proses', 'dalam proses', 'dalam proses', 'dalam proses', 'dalam proses', 'dalam proses','dalam proses','belum terbaca')";
            mysqli_query($koneksi_cuti, $query);
             if($query){
            echo "<script>alert('Pengajuan Cuti Berhasil')</script>";           
            echo "<script>window.open('user.php','_self')</script>";
            }
        }else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO:  Cuti Tahunan Harus H-30 Sebelum Bercuti");</script>';
        }
    }
```